# Trying to stream audio from USB recording device

Tags: audio, usb

I'm trying to use `libusb-1.0` to pull audio samples through an isochronous transfer on a USB recording device. I imagined that for an isochronous transfer this would be easy, i.e. no control transmissions needed, just connect and read from the designated interface, but what I'm reading *appears to be device information*. (See the hexdump below. See source code file on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/aQXvuKWR).)

So my question is **how do I stream audio from a USB device?** (I've read [USB In a Nutshell](http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb1.shtml). I've confirmed that the interface, alternate setting, and endpoint I'm using are for Isochronous OUT by using `lsusb -v`. See [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/uc454GN8) for full device information.) I don't think that I need to (or can) send any control signals to alter the configuration of clocks/channels/interrupts because the control interface has no endpoints (as you can see in the foregoing link).

Here's the "character" portion of the top of a `hexdump -C` from the packets I captured with `libusb-1.0`. (See the whole hexdump at [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/dbs7QaUN)):

```
................................14.0/usb2/2-3.2-0:1.0...........
`.......x.......................1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0.1.5:1.0...
`.......x.......`.......0.......................b2/2-0:1.0......
0.......1........!..............................14.0/usb2/2-0:1.
0...............................@.............DEVTYPE.usb_inte
rface.DRIVER.hub.PRODUCT.1d6b/2/404.TYPE.9/0/0.INTERFACE.9/0/0.M
ODALIAS.usb:v1D6Bp0002d0404dc09dsc00dp00ic09isc00ip00in00.......
................................................................
...............................................DEVTYPE.usb_inte
rface.DRIVER.hub.PRODUCT.1d6b/3/404.TYPE.9/0/3.INTERFACE.9/0/0.M
ODALIAS.usb:v1D6Bp0003d0404dc09dsc00dp03ic09isc00ip00in00.......
................*................................14.0/usb2/2-3.2-
0:1.0...........`.......x.......................1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-
1:1.0.1.5:1.0...`.......x.......`.......0.......................
b2/2-0:1.0......0.......1........!..............................
14.0/usb2/2-0:1.0...............................* @ ....... ......
```

Comment: USB audio at this layer is actually crazy complicated.  It's not as simple as just getting data in... setup is involved for sample rate, channels, mixers, sample format, etc.  Is there a reason you need to do this directly rather than letting the drivers handle it?

Comment: @Brad : I need to do this on Android, and I don't have a driver. I attempted to use `AudioRecord` from the Android API, but I was unable to make it source a USB device. Do you know of anything I can read for details on the setup that you mentioned? (I've looked at the formats document on USB audio at usb.org, and I'm now looking at the "class definition for audio devices" document, but I should be surprised if there were controls I could send to my recording device.)

Comment: @Brad : 2 questions: Is it possible to learn what control signals I need so send without the cooperation of the vendor? Do you know anything about Android's AudioRecord for USB Audio?

Comment: @Brad : I will put a bounty on this question if you think you can get me where I need to go.

Comment: I'm not completely familiar with the APIs on Android... I haven't written an Android app since Froyo/2.1 and I never ended up releasing it.  But, I have looked into this issue on Android quite a bit.  At least one person has written a userland driver for class-compliant USB audio.  http://www.extreamsd.com/index.php/products/usb-audio-recorder-pro  It's my understanding that it took a long time, and the driver is just now getting to a point of decent reliability.  Maybe you could just license it?

Comment: The other thing is that on  Android 5 and later, USB audio capture works just fine.  There's nothing else you have to do but do a normal audio record and the underlying system handles it for you.  (I think Android 3.1 and later had USB audio playback.)  I can even access USB audio from web pages now, which is why I abandoned my old Android native app.  (I made an internet radio encoder which works with getUserMedia... all in browser so everyone can use it without an app install.)